# join and select multi values for each row

Tags: mysql, php

i have 2 tables, `users` and `skills`
in skills i save skill ids and each user can have multiple skills

now i want to select all users with each user's all skill ids

but with join i cant, and with sub query i get

> Cardinality violation: 1242 Sub query returns more than 1 row

how should query be written ?

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as:

```
SELECT  U.ID, S.ID
FROM    SKILL S
INNER JOIN USER U      -- in case you want more user details in the results.
ON      U.ID = S.USER_ID
ORDER BY U.ID, S.ID
```

Will retrieve all the users and each skill they have.

If Skills is not a child of User (i.e. each skill can also be associated with multiple users) then you need a USER_SKILL table to link the two together. Then the query would be:

```
SELECT  USER_ID, SKILL_ID
FROM    USER_SKILL
ORDER BY USER_ID, SKILL_ID
```

In future it is a good idea to include the query you are using (which caused the error) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Inner Join, this will bring all users with having a match skill/s in skill table. Your code would be like:

```
select U.username, S.Skillid --- you can add more columns per your need
From UserTable  U
Join SkillTable S
ON   U.userid = S.skillid -- assuming you have userid and skillid as PK and FK relationship. 
Order by U.Userid
```